# Duplicate fields despite using unique validation in Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

In Laravel I have an API which allows users to register.

The registration has a simple validation for emails to be unique and looks something like this:

```
public function register(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users|max:255',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|max:50',
    ]);

    // create new user and save model
}
```

Unfortunately, I still found quite a few users in my table with duplicate emails.

I believe the reason for this is that my app sometimes sends same request, multiple times, in quick succession. This means both request passes the validation despite having the same email as they have not been added to the database yet.

How can I fix this issue to ensure uniqueness for emails?

Comment: How about using an `UNIQUE` key for your `email` column in your DB? You could then check if you get an SQL Error with Code 1062, which repesents the error `Duplicate Entry <value> for key <xyz> in <abc>`.

Comment: Yes I was planning to add a unique key, but I wanted to be able to detect and handle the error. How can I handle the error like you mentioned.

Comment: You can use a `try-catch block` when actually inserting the data:

Comment: But that will just check for any exception. How do I detect for that specific exception.

Comment: what about the update method validation ?

Comment: First of all if you require unique email for users, you should fix your database, then you will get a duplicate exception from laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `try-catch block` when actually inserting the data (see the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) for more Information):

```
try {
  $connection->query(<yourInsertquery>);
  return true;
} catch (PDOException $e){
  if ($e->getCode() == 1062){
    return 'duplicate';
  }
  return false;
}
```

With this you will get a String `'duplicate'` returned whenever you have duplicated entries, otherwise `false` in case of an different error and `true`

Answer (score 1):

Use this custom fucntion in your validation of input like this example

```
   $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), [

            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => [
                'required',
                'email',
                    function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                        if (Employee::where('email',$value)->count() > 0) {
                            $fail($attribute.'already exits');
                        }
                    },
            ],
        ]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Or simply prevent multiple submission of that same form by disabling the submit button on the client side... It is unlikely that you will get the same email address from two sessions submitted simultaneously...

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#button').click(function () {
            $('#button').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#Form').submit();
            return true;
        });

    });
```

You can do something like this server side by generating a token for the form and saving that token to the session locking that form into only one submission... Many ways to skin that cat. The previous answer works as well but you need a round trip to the database... This one has no performance penalty (although this is a fringe case and should be negligeable...)

Hope this helps